# How to add a "Buy now" button BEFORE to "Add to cart" button (WordPress/Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I wanna add a `"Buy Now"` button `BEFORE` to `"Add to cart"` button. I already tried with an others solutions here, but they all are for buttons `after` to `"Add Cart"` button.

*Example:*

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity` hook as following

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity', 'by_now' );

function by_now() {

    echo '<div class="test"> buy now </div>';
}
```

in your css add :

```
.test {
display: inline-block;
 }
.woocommerce div.product form.cart .button {
vertical-align: middle;
float: none !important ;
}
```

**Output**

[image]

**output in your site**

[image]
you need to place the code inside your `functions.php`

Comment: damn it, for some reason the button still positioned after to "Add to cart" button, ¿Any idea? ¿Theme issue?

Comment: @edavila show me your site link it's might be  css

Comment: you can add before or after "add to cart" button only.

Comment: @GufranHasan you can add it whatever you want there is several hooks for that

Comment: @kashalo there is it --> https://armexshop.com/producto/modelo-065/

Comment: @edavila it'''s under maintenance

Comment: @kashalo try again, sorry

Comment: @edavila  you are wrapping the whole from with your dic i edit my answer with div tag

Comment: @edavila i edit my answer so you can use another hook try it now

Comment: @edavila now just remove float: left;  to add to cart button :)

Comment: @kashalo it works! Thank a lot bro!

Comment: @edavila always pleasure  :)

Comment: But what happens when someone clicks on the `buy now` button? How do we, upon the click of the button, add the product to cart and redirect them to the cart page?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `"Buy Now"` `before` by using hook `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button`.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'custom_content_before_addtocart_button', 100 );
function custom_content_before_addtocart_button() {
    // custom content.
    echo 'Buy Now';
}
```

[image]

You can add `"Buy Now"` `after` by using hook `woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button`.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'custom_content_after_addtocart_button', 100 );
function custom_content_after_addtocart_button() {
    // custom content.
    echo 'Buy Now';
}
```

Comment: you can add "Buy Now" before or after of  "add to cart" button by using hooks.